# How to estimate sortkey by skew_sortkey1 in SVV_TABLE_INFO?

Tags: amazon-redshift

According to AWS reference below, "skew_sortkey1" is useful value to evaluate the effectiveness of the current sort key, but I can’t completely understand it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SVV_TABLE_INFO.html

Let me show you some example. Below tables have same sort key, p_date (purchse_date) but different skew_sortkey1 value.

Then may I ask if I can say "table_a has more effective sort key, since it has high value than table_b" ?

Highly appreciated any of your feedback.

```
example:
select "table", encoded, diststyle, skew_sortkey1, skew_rows from svv_table_info order by 1;

table          | encoded | diststyle       | skew_sortkey1 | skew_rows
---------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+----------
table_a            Y         KEY(P_DATE)    67.73           1.16
table_b            Y         KEY(P_DATE)    3.52            1.86
```

Thanks to all of your expert advice here, we successed to migrate our Redshift two month ago and it's running without big issue.
Although it's quite fast more than our expectations, I think it's time to evaluate current setting is appropriate or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rationale for "skew_sortkey1" is discussed in a couple of answers on this question: [What does the column skew_sorkey1 in Amazon Redshift's svv_table_info imply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857481/what-does-the-column-skew-sorkey1-in-amazon-redshifts-svv-table-info-imply)

Basically larger values for this column are less desirable because the greater the skew, the more blocks of data Redshift is having to scan. In the case of table_a in your example, for every one block of the sort key column that gets scanned Redshift has to scan up to ~68 blocks of other columns to retrieve data.

One cause for high skew values is compression on the sort key columns:

[image]

(Source: https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/bdt401-amazon-redshift-deep-dive-tuning-and-best-practices)

So if you have compressed the sort key columns on these tables, consider removing the compression and leaving them uncompressed.

Comment: I really appreciated again for your clear and useful explanation -- thanks to your kind correction, now I undersatnd high value of skew_sortkey1 should be avoided on Redshift. First, we'll try the uncompression according to your great advice. Thank you so much !